# Change dynamically option parameters of the Google Charts (Gauge Chart)

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Is it possible any way to change dynamically the option parameters of a googles charts? (in my case the google gauge chart)
I have tried to do it using variables but without success:

```
    var limit=20;
    var gaugeOptions = {min: -15, max: 50, redFrom: limit, redTo:40, minorTicks: 5};
    ...
    ...
    ...
    gauge_temp.draw(gaugeData, gaugeOptions);
```

Here, I try to modify dynamically the option "redFrom" through the variable limit. But the result is a gauge without colors around the circle.

I want that the user can configure the gauge options like the color of the gauge segments directly from the webpage( redFrom, yellowFrom,...).

Comment: That should work, provided that `limit` is a non-null number and not a string (eg, `10` is valid, but `'10'` is not; if you are getting the value from an HTML input, it is probably a string that you have to parse as a number first, ie `redFrom: parseInt(limit)`).

Comment: asgallant, you are right now it works.